# Homotopic Topology by Fukes, Fomenko, Gutenmacher

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of the English translation of the book *Homotopic Topology* by the authors mentioned in the title? A professor has recommended this book with a lot of enthusiasm, but Amazon does not have any copies. Also, and this came as a surprise to me, my department library also does not have a copy of this apparent gem.

It seems this book is out of print, or at least the English translation is, and I will be much obliged if someone who has an online copy, or knows where I can find one, can contact me at (my MSE username without capitalization)@gmail.com

Thanks.

======================

## [image]

Comment: As with Berkeley, one may assume that Columbia had problems with book theft prior to the introduction of those little inserts in the book spines. Note that the Berkeley copy is a photocopy, bound in 2009. Your best bet is likely interlibrary loan, which may require a faculty member asking for you.

Answer (score 9):

For the benefit of everybody, Prof. Mikhail Khovanov has photocopied the entire book, which is now available on his website http://www.math.columbia.edu/~khovanov/algtop2013/.

Comment: Thanks, it is a very nice book !

Answer (score 1):

See the book in pdf files on [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/vaguten/homotopic-topology)

Comment: I think it is the version which is on Prof. Khovanov's website.

Answer (score 1):

new Springer edition to be published in 2016: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319234878

Comment: This should be posted as a comment and not as an answer.